# Piping cmd output to variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following in a PowerShell script:

```
cmd /c npm run build-release 
$succeeded = $LastExitCode
```

What I'd like to do is:

1. Pipe the output of the `cmd` to a variable so it doesn't write to the host
2. *Only* if `$succeeded` is `eq $true`, `Write-Host` the output variable from that the `cmd`

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Invoke-Expression`:

```
$output = Invoke-Expression "cmd /c npm run build-release"
$succeeded = $LastExitCode

if($succeeded -eq 0) {
  write-output $output
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought you actually need Invoke-Expression for this. Does it have to do with how `npm` works? `$results = ping 127.0.0.1` works fine for example

Comment: @Matt I think its better from a readability point of view - it's more clear your calling something external. Its also useful if the command was ever built into a variable.